# Flutter/Dart how to groupBy list of maps

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this list of maps.

```
[
    {title: 'Avengers', release_date: '10/01/2019'},
    {title: 'Creed', release_date: '10/01/2019'}
    {title: 'Jumanji', release_date: '30/10/2019'},
]
```

I would like to write a code that would group the list of movies by `release_date` like that.

```
[
   {
      "10/01/2019": [
         {
            "title": "Avengers"
         },
         {
            "title": "Creed"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "30/10/2019": [
         {
            "title": "Jumanji"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how did you get data like 'var data' as mentioned above, when fetching data from API, because when I tried to get data from API it gives me data in (key,value) pair.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The package [collection](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/collection) implements
the `groupBy` function.

For grouping by date:

```
import "package:collection/collection.dart";

main(List<String> args) {
  var data = [
    {"title": 'Avengers', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
    {"title": 'Creed', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
    {"title": 'Jumanji', "release_date": '30/10/2019'},
  ];


  var newMap = groupBy(data, (Map obj) => obj['release_date']);

  print(newMap);
}
```

For removing the `release_date` key from each map entry:

```
var newMap = groupBy(data, (Map obj) => obj['release_date']).map(
    (k, v) => MapEntry(k, v.map((item) { item.remove('release_date'); return item;}).toList()));
```

For changing a key:

```
var newMap = groupBy(data, (Map obj) => obj['release_date']).map(
    (k, v) => MapEntry(k, v.map((item) => {'name': item['title']}).toList()));
```

Comment: Note that this `groupBy` is not part of the [`dart:collection`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-collection/dart-collection-library.html) -- this references a [third-party collection](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/collection) package.

Comment: How do I groupby on year in the same above example? release_date is still in Date format

Comment: Since `collection 1.15.0-nullsafety.4`, you can replace it with `data.groupListsBy((obj) => ...)`. https://github.com/dart-lang/collection/blob/1.15.0/lib/src/iterable_extensions.dart#L389

Comment: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'.
This is error I am getting on 
var newMap = groupBy(data, (obj) => obj['release_date']);

Comment: Add Map to (obj) -> (Map obj) to solve this

Comment: info: Only use double quotes for strings containing single quotes.

Comment: @Kisakyamukama please provide a more clearly worded answer.

Answer (score 74):

If you have **Dart 2.7**, you can *extend* `Iterable` to add a useful `groupBy` method:

```dart
extension Iterables<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Map<K, List<E>> groupBy<K>(K Function(E) keyFunction) => fold(
      <K, List<E>>{},
      (Map<K, List<E>> map, E element) =>
          map..putIfAbsent(keyFunction(element), () => <E>[]).add(element));
}
```

Now, you're *List of Maps*, could be grouped using something like:

```dart
final releaseDateMap = listOfMaps.groupBy((m) => m['release_date'])
```

Data like this:

```
[
    {title: 'Avengers', release_date: '10/01/2019'},
    {title: 'Creed', release_date: '10/01/2019'}
    {title: 'Jumanji', release_date: '30/10/2019'},
]
```

would turn into:

```
{
  '10/01/2019': [
    {title: 'Avengers', release_date: '10/01/2019'},
    {title: 'Creed', release_date: '10/01/2019'}
  ],
  '30/10/2019': [
    {title: 'Jumanji', release_date: '30/10/2019'},
  ]
}
```

Comment: What if we have list of custom objects?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher you can use this the same way with custom objects as well. 

For example `final lastNameMap = listOfPeople.groupBy((person) => person.lastName);`

Comment: I prefer to use this approach rather than adding a new dependency on the project.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why no one has mentioned that with how basic built-in functions and methods you can achieve it, like:

```dart
main() {
  List<Map> data = [
    {'title': 'Avengers', 'release_date': '10/01/2019'},
    {'title': 'Creed', 'release_date': '10/01/2019'},
    {'title': 'Jumanji', 'release_date': '30/10/2019'},
  ];

  // Loop through empty {} map and check if the release date exists, if not
  // add as the key and empty list as the value, then fill the list with element
  // itself, removing 'release_date' before adding. Then you can map the map
  // to a list of maps.
  List result = data
      .fold({}, (previousValue, element) {
        Map val = previousValue as Map;
        String date = element['release_date'];
        if (!val.containsKey(date)) {
          val[date] = [];
        }
        element.remove('release_date');
        val[date]?.add(element);
        return val;
      })
      .entries
      .map((e) => {e.key: e.value})
      .toList();

  print(result);
}
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\duoqu\Desktop>dart run test.dart
[{10/01/2019: [{title: Avengers}, {title: Creed}]}, {30/10/2019: [{title: Jumanji}]}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
extension UtilListExtension on List{
  groupBy(String key) {
    try {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = [];
      List<String> keys = [];

      this.forEach((f) => keys.add(f[key]));

      [...keys.toSet()].forEach((k) {
        List data = [...this.where((e) => e[key] == k)];
        result.add({k: data});
      });

      return result;
    } catch (e, s) {
      printCatchNReport(e, s);
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

then use it like this

```
var data = [
    {"title": 'Avengers', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
    {"title": 'Creed', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
    {"title": 'Jumanji', "release_date": '30/10/2019'},
];

var result = data.groupBy('title');
print(result);
```

then the result is

```
[{10/01/2019: [{title: Avengers, release_date: 10/01/2019}, {title: Creed, release_date: 10/01/2019}]}, {30/10/2019: [{title: Jumanji, release_date: 30/10/2019}]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a method naively implemented (in case you don't want to use the groupBy function from the collections package):

```
List<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> MapByKey(String keyName, String newKeyName, String keyForNewName, List<Map<String,String>> input) {
  Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> returnValue = Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>();
  for (var currMap in input) {
    if (currMap.containsKey(keyName)) {
      var currKeyValue = currMap[keyName];
      var currKeyValueForNewName = currMap[keyForNewName];
      if (!returnValue.containsKey(currKeyValue)){
        returnValue[currKeyValue] = {currKeyValue : List<Map<String, String>>()};  
      }
      returnValue[currKeyValue][currKeyValue].add({newKeyName : currKeyValueForNewName});
    }
  }
  return returnValue.values.toList();
}

void main() {
    var test = [
    {"title": 'Avengers', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
    {"title": 'Creed', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
    {"title": 'Jumanji', "release_date": '30/10/2019'},
  ];

  var testMapped = MapByKey("release_date", "name", "title", test);

  print("$testMapped");
}
```

The output is:

```
[
    {
        10/01/2019: [
            {name: Avengers
            },
            {name: Creed
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        30/10/2019: [
            {name: Jumanji
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't know why I wrote `name` instead of `title` in the result but you solved my problem thanks!

Comment: Group is a subset of Fold. I think that an implementation based on Fold would perform better and be more readable.

Comment: @Oswin Noetzelmann Can you please let me know how did you get data like 'var test' as mentioned above, when fetching data from API, because when I tried to get data from API it gives me data in (key,value) pair.

Comment: @Darshana the var test example is the exact structure that the OP had asked for in his question above.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the accepted answer if you come arcross this, In flutter 2, you will Get an error, as i got.

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)'
```

Use

```
var data = [
     {"title": 'Avengers', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
     {"title": 'Creed', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
     {"title": 'Jumanji', "release_date": '30/10/2019'},
   ];


   var newMap = groupBy(data, (Map oj) => oj['release_date']);

   print(newMap);
```

This might be of help to someone.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [supercharged](https://pub.dev/packages/supercharged) package, you'd write it like this:

```
List list = [
  { title: 'Avengers', release_date: '10/01/2019' },
  { title: 'Creed', release_date: '10/01/2019' }
  { title: 'Jumanji', release_date: '30/10/2019' },
];

final map = list.groupBy<String, Map>((item) => 
  item['release_date'],
  valueTransform: (item) => item..remove('release_date'),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

It may not be the best solution. But it can give you an idea

```
List arrayData = [
  {"name": 'John', "gender": 'male'},
  {"name": 'James', "gender": 'male'},
  {"name": 'Mary', "gender": 'female'}
];
```

Retrieve list ​​by gender:

```
List males = arrayData.where((o) => o['gender'] == "male").toList();
List females = arrayData.where((o) => o['gender'] == "female").toList();
```

Make new map with desired format:

```
List result = [
  {
    "male": males.map((f) => {"name": f['name']}).toList()
  },
  {
    "female": females.map((f) => {"name": f['name']}).toList()
  }
];
```

print:

```
debugPrint('${result}');
```

result:

```
[{male: [{name: John}, {name: James}]}, {female: [{name: Mary}]}]
```

Comment: Scan the list extracting the group-by value into a `HashSet` then, for each member of that set, use @EdHuamani's `where` syntax.

Comment: I just edited my problem. 

As you see, the key I need to `groupBy` is dynamic so I can't use this method.