# Dart Experts - Group List by distinct value, and calculate sum

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dart list:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

//Car(brand, quantity)

Car car = new Car ("nissan", 2);
cars.add(car);

car = new Car("nissan", 4);
cars.add(car);

car = new Car("toyota", 3);
cars.add(car);

car = new Car("nissan", 5);
cars.add(car);

car = new Car("toyota", 2);
cars.add(car);
```

How can i get a list of Cars which should only contains 2 records (which is the sum of the quantity):

```
Car("nissan", 11)
Car("toyota", 5)
```

Comment: quiz time!!! Seriously, StackOverflow expect you to have some kind of codes that you've tried before throwing us the problem... Btw, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: The values `Car("nissan", 11)` or `Car("toyota", 5)` don't exist in your cars list, so this cannot be answerred.

Comment: @Steven but if you group car makers add sum the quantity...

Comment: In that case, there's a solid question in here if it's worded correctly. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `map` literal and then count using a `forEach` loop.

```dart
  var carMap = {};
  cars.forEach((car) {
    String key = car.brand;
    if (carMap.containsKey(key)) {
      carMap[key] += car.quantity;
    } else {
      carMap[key] = car.quantity;
    }
  });
  print(carMap);
```

Comment: better use `groupBy` top level function in that case

Comment: How can i use groupBy in this situation?

Comment: @Manish many thanks for your answer, ..actually i have more attribute in this list (ex. Maker, quantity, description) and wanted to sum quantity by maker and return it as “List<Cars>”... ?

Comment: @Aexperty this should guide you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029370/flutter-dart-how-to-groupby-list-of-maps/54036449

Comment: @Aexperty How does description get reduced i.e. How does the `description` in different objects gets combined; like sum, append, take first etc?

Comment: @manish ... let us take it with another example like "category" ... it is a more clear example of the case ... category for all nissan records are same "nissanCategory", and for all toyota also same "toyotaCategory".

Comment: @Manish .. appreciate if you can guide in this regard

Comment: @ariefbayu here OP is showing a List<Car> with properties. He is not stating this coming straight from a JSON fetch.