# Flutter/Dart group list by date

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following list of maps,

```
[
   {
      "FullName":"Harry Potter",
      "DateOfBirth": "2020/02/16",
      "Department":"Branch Operation",
      "BirthDay":"Friday"
   },
   {
      "FullName":"John Wick",
      "DateOfBirth": "2020/02/16",
      "Department":"Finance",
      "BirthDay":"Friday"
   },
   {
      "FullName":"Solomon Kane",
      "DateOfBirth":2020/02/19,
      "Department":"Loan",
      "BirthDay":"Monday"
   }
]
```

I would like to manipulate above data such that data are grouped by their `DateOfBirth`, so that result would look like this.

```
[
   {
      "DateOfBirth": "2020/02/16",
      "BirthDay": "Friday",
      "Data":[
         {
            "FullName": "Harry Potter",
            "Department":"Branch Operation",
         },
         {
            "FullName":"John Wick",
            "Department":"Finance",
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "DateOfBirth": "2020/02/19",
      "BirthDay": "Monday",
      "Data":[
         {
            "FullName":"Solomon Kane",
            "Department":"Loan"
         }
      ]
   },
]
```

In Javascript, this can be achieved by using `reduce` function and then using Object key mapping.
I also know dart has useful package called  [`collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection)

As I am new to dart and flutter, I am not sure how to do. Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter/Dart how to groupBy list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029370/flutter-dart-how-to-groupby-list-of-maps)

Comment: @Pavel, I've gone through that answer, but my requirement is slightly different, than the OP's requirement in that thread.

Comment: What if two objects have same DateOfBirth but different BirthDay?

Comment: @Pavel if DOB is same BirthDay will always be same, its a Day person was born.

Comment: The data structure doesn't guarantee this, so you'll need to handle this situation anyway. Maybe get BirthDay of the first person with this BirthDay or throw an exception

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [fold](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/fold.html) and do something like this

```
const data = [...];

void main() {
 final value = data.fold(Map<String, List<dynamic>>(), (Map<String, List<dynamic>> a, b) {
   a.putIfAbsent(b['DateOfBirth'], () => []).add(b);
   return a;
 }).values
   .where((l) => l.isNotEmpty)
   .map((l) => {
     'DateOfBirth': l.first['DateOfBirth'],
     'BirthDay': l.first['BirthDay'],
     'Data': l.map((e) => {
       'Department': e['Department'],
       'FullName': e['FullName'],
     }).toList()
 }).toList();
}
```

Or like this if you want to use the spread operator, I don't know if its very readable though.

```
 final result = data.fold({}, (a, b) => {
     ...a,
     b['DateOfBirth']: [b, ...?a[b['DateOfBirth']]],
 }).values
   .where((l) => l.isNotEmpty)
   .map((l) => {
     'DateOfBirth': l.first['DateOfBirth'],
     'BirthDay': l.first['BirthDay'],
     'Data': l.map((e) => {
       'Department': e['Department'],
       'FullName': e['FullName'],
     }).toList()
 }).toList();
```

Comment: The second one helped my code shorter very much. Thank you @gugge.
In my case, it was:
```dart
    final result = datas.fold({}, (a, b) => {
      ...a, b.capturedDate: [b, ...?a[b.capturedDate]],
    }).values.toList();
 ```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question.
The best solution: use inner extentions. See [IterableExtension](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension.html)

Update pubspec.yaml and use it.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/groupListsBy.html

```
pubspec.yaml
...
dependencies:
  collection: any
```

```
      final Map<String, List<ItemType>> result =
          data.groupListsBy((item) => item.timeField.year.toString());
```