# Comparing calendar datetime to yyyy-mm-dd format in flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, calendar

I have a calendar and in the calendar events are added in here 
`Map<DateTime, List<EventStore>> get events => _events;`

where EventStore is anotherClass like this,

```
class EventStore{
  String subject;
  String level;
  String room;
  EventStore({this.subject,this.level,this.room});
}
```

Now, I want to compare today's date in yyyy-mm-dd format with the calendar date format. And I also don't know how to see the calendar date format. 
**How do I compare today's date in yyyy-mm-dd format with the calendar date format? So that I can show all the events that are on the particular date anywhere in my app?**
And can anybody say, what is the DateTime format in map, 
  `Map<DateTime, List<EventStore>> get events => _events;`

Answer (score 0):

DateTime objects don't contain a date format, it's technically a number of elapsed time since 01-01-1970 https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

You can compare DateTime objects using their attributes.

```dart
DateTime savedDateTime = getSavedDateFromServer();
DateTime now = DateTime.now();

bool isSameYear = savedDateTime.year == now.year;
bool isSameMonth = savedDateTime.month == now.month;
//etc.
```

If you want to group your objects by date I recommend you take a look at this:
[Flutter/Dart how to groupBy list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029370/flutter-dart-how-to-groupby-list-of-maps)