# How to group a list of Locations

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this list of WorldTime with keys, How do I group these list by the location key.
Below is the code i have written.

````
List<WorldTime> locations = [
    WorldTime(url: 'Europe/London', location: 'London', flag: 'London.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Abidjan',location:'Abidjan'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Accra', location: 'Accra', flag: 'ghana.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Algeria', location: 'Algiers', flag: 'Algeria.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Guinea ', location: 'Bassau', flag: 'Guinea'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Cairo', location: 'Cairo', flag: 'Egypt.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Casablanca', location: 'Casablanca', flag: 'Casablanca.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Ceuta ', location: 'Ceuta', flag: 'Ceuta.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/El_Aaiun', location: 'El_Aaiun', flag: 'El_Aaiun'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Johannesburg', location: 'Johannesburg', flag: 'Johannesburg.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Juba', location: 'Juba', flag: 'Juba.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Khartoum', location: 'Khartoum', flag: 'Khartoum.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Lagos', location: 'Lagos', flag: 'Lagos.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Maputo', location: 'Maputo', flag: 'Maputo.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Monrovia', location: 'Monrovia', flag: 'Monrovia.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Nairobi', location: 'Nairobi', flag: 'Nairobi.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Ndjamena', location: 'Ndjamena', flag: 'Ndjamena.png'),
```![End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVPHK.png)
````

Comment: do you mean sort or group? group will make sense if location can be repeated. I don't see that here.

Comment: group. Some locations are instances of a url like America

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are trying to do based on your question. Please provide a description/example of the result you expect from this "grouping"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter/Dart how to groupBy list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029370/flutter-dart-how-to-groupby-list-of-maps)

Comment: Ok I will provide a result

Answer (score 1):

Dart collections does not have a group function like Kotlin, but you can use this lib: https://pub.dev/packages/supercharged

Now you can group:

```
List<WorldTime> locations = [
WorldTime(url: 'Europe/London', location: 'London', flag: 'London.png'),
WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Abidjan',location:'London'),
WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Accra', location: 'Accra', flag: 'ghana.png'),
WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Algeria', location: 'Algiers', flag: 'Algeria.png'),
]

locations.groupBy((element) => element.location == 'London' ? "currentLocation" : "otherLocations")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to **sort** the list by location? (Sorry your question is a little confusing)

You can use the [List.sort()](https://api.dart.dev/be/137051/dart-core/List/sort.html) function, it would look like this:

```
locations.sort((a,b) => a.location.compareTo(b.location));
print(locations)
```

Comment: its group not sort

Comment: @G-Codes Why would you group when items are unique?

Comment: this is the problem I have, is there a way around it? because some locations like America having various cities with different time zones can't be left alone. I need to group them under America

Comment: America would be the Continent, the locations being cities would still be unique wouldn't it? Could you give an example?