# Manupulate Group Wise Data in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to show, first of all, the Group name then below all child products of the particular group. but I can not populate the data.
still, now, show data 1) group name 2) product name of the particular group.
I want to display the result

1. Group Name
   a) product name
   b) product name
   c) product name
   d) product name
   my source code given is below:

   ```
   body:
          ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: _mOfferList == null
                  ? 0
                  : _mOfferList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                return Card(
                  // margin:
                  //     EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
                    elevation: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          _mOfferList[
                          index].offerBaseProductBrandTitle,
                          textAlign:
                          TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13.0),

                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            // Emp Info
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                // color: Color(0xFF90EE90),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 1,
                                          child:
                                          _mOfferList[index].offerTitle ==
                                              null
                                              ? Text("  ",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13.0))
                                              : Text(
                                            "" +
                                                _mOfferList[
                                                index].offerTitle,
                                            textAlign:
                                            TextAlign.left,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 13.0),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            // end of Emp Info
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ));
              }),
   ```

[image: my result output:]

wanted result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZJSq.png)

Stil now my result:
Group Name : AAA
a) abc
Group Name : AAA
b) xxx
Group Name : AAA
c) yyy
Group Name : AAA
d) zzz
Group Name : BBB
a) gtt
Group Name : BBB
b) gbt
Group Name : BBB
c) kosadfa
Group Name : BBB
d) sdfsadf

But my wanted result: like below

```
Group Name : AAA
        a) abc
        b) xxx
        c) yyy
        d) zzz
Group Name : BBB
        a) gtt
        b) gbt
        c) kosadfa
        d) sdfsadf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used `group_list_view` package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/group_list_view) hope its help to you

You also try [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-grouped-list/)

Try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qb_uRUuFF3U) video also

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54036449/13997210) answer also