# GroupedListView in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have group of data grouped by date. I want to find **sum of total** in each group.

[image]

How can I find total sum of each group?

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134029/13997210) hope its helpful to you.

Comment: Please add the code you already have.

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil, Thank you. Your answer is helpful.

Comment: @BinodBhandari if your problem has been solved my answer please upvote it.Thanks

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil, Sure brother.