# Sorting a list into smaller lists according to a characteristic in dart

Tags: list, sorting, dart

Sorry for my poor explanation, I just started learning dart.

With a mock service and a json file I created a set amount of items

Example:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "type": "a"
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "type": "b"
    },
    {
      "id": "03",
      "type": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

when creating the list on the service it creates a single list like this:

```
     if (json['items'] != null) {
          final itemList = <ItemList>[];
          json['items'].forEach((v) {
            itemlistList.add(ItemList.fromJson(v));
          });
          return ItemList;
        } else {
          return [];
        }
```

is there a way to, form the create list step to already separate them into 3 different lists for the type a, b, and c items? and if now, where and how would I divide this itemlist into 3 based on the type characteristic of each item?

Comment: Would this help? [Flutter/dart: How to groupBy list of maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029370/flutter-dart-how-to-groupby-list-of-maps)

Comment: @Stef Not really, I don't need small lists inside a sorted big one, I need something like and If statement that if it is "type a" then ad to "TypeAList" and the item is fully-added to such independent list, same for the other types.

Comment: Yes, I believe what you describe is exactly what groupBy does.

Comment: Not really, I need an if statement to sort out element by element

Answer (score 0):

Using **groupBy**, as suggested in this extremely similar question: [Flutter/Dart how to groupBy list of maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029370/flutter-dart-how-to-groupby-list-of-maps)

```dart
import "package:collection/collection.dart";

main(List<String> args) {
  var data = [
    {"id": "01", "type": "a"},
    {"id": "02", "type": "b"},
    {"id": "03", "type": "c"},
    {"id": "04", "type": "a"},
    {"id": "05", "type": "a"},
    {"id": "06", "type": "b"},
  ];

  var newMap = groupBy(data, (Map obj) => obj["type"]);

  print(newMap);
}
```