# Flutter/Dart how to groupBy list of maps from json

Tags: json, dart, group-by, collections

This question  is almost identical to the one answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54036449/3185563) The difference is that my data is **json**, coming from an API call. This is causing the error shown at the bottom of the code below. I've tried various combinations of casting and variable types with no success.

```
        import 'dart:convert';
        import "package:collection/collection.dart";
        
        void main(List<String> args) {
          var data1 = [
            {"title": 'Avengers', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
            {"title": 'Creed', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
            {"title": 'Jumanji', "release_date": '30/10/2019'},
          ];
           //without these two lines, the code executes with no problems
          var data2 = jsonEncode(data1);
          var data3 = jsonDecode(data2);
        
          try {
            var newMap = groupBy(data3, (Map obj) => obj['release_date']);
            print(newMap);
          } catch (err) {
            print(err);
          }
    
    **type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'**




  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54036449/3185563
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static and runtime type of `data1` is `List<Map<String, String>>`, which is inferred from the contents of the literal.

The runtime type of `data3` is `List<dynamic>`, because that's what `jsonDecode` creates. The static type is just `dynamic`.

You can't pass a `List<dynamic>` to something expecting an `Iterable<Map>`, which is what your `groupBy` expects (inferred just from the `(Map obj) => ...` function since the other argument has type `dynamic`), and why you get the error.

You can type `data3` as `List data3 = jsonDecode(...);`. That will likely force type inference to guess `dynamic` as the type argument to `groupBy`. Then you will get an error that `(Map obj) => ...` doesn't accept `dynamic`, though.

You can, with or without the above, change `(Map obj)` into `(dynamic obj)`, that should make the code run, by skipping the type checking. Or you can do
`(dynamic obj) => (obj as Map)["release_date"]` to do the cast before the lookup.

You can type `data3` as `List` and then cast it to `List<Map>` by doing `data3.cast<Map>().groupBy((Map obj) => ...)`. (You can use `groupBy` as an extension method too, I recommend doing so, but it only works if the receiver, `data3`, has a non-`dynamic` type.)