# Summarize List<Map<String,dynamic> elements

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, sum

I have a sales List like below:

```
 List<Map<String,dynamic>> sales = [
    {'paid': 2000, 'name': 'person1'},
    {'paid': 2500, 'name': 'person2'},
    {'paid': 5600, 'name': 'person1'},
    {'paid': 974.0, 'name': 'person2'},
  ];
```

I want to sum persons' paid amount and show in a ListView.builder like below:

person1 : 7600
person2 : 3474

I need a hand with how to calculate every individual person inside a map in Dart/Flutter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first of all, you need to groupby the name field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code might help you:

```
   void main() {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> sales = [
        {'paid': 2000, 'name': 'person1'},
        {'paid': 2500, 'name': 'person2'},
        {'paid': 5600, 'name': 'person1'},
        {'paid': 974.0, 'name': 'person2'},
      ];
    
      Map map = Map();
      for (var sale in sales) {
        if (map.keys.contains(sale['name'])) {
          map[sale["name"]] = map[sale["name"]] + sale['paid'];
        } else
          map[sale["name"]] = sale['paid'];
      }
      print(map.toString());
    }
```

where the output would be:

```
{person1: 7600, person2: 3474.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a method a bit more verbose but that would allow you top keep a reference on your results.

```dart
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> sales = [
    {'paid': 2000, 'name': 'person1'},
    {'paid': 2500, 'name': 'person2'},
    {'paid': 5600, 'name': 'person1'},
    {'paid': 974.0, 'name': 'person2'},
  ];

  final salesByName = <String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>{};
  
  for (final entry in sales) {
    if (salesByName.keys.contains(entry["name"] as String)) {
      salesByName[entry["name"] as String]?.add(entry);
    } else {
      salesByName[entry["name"] as String] = [entry];
    }
  }

  final salesByNameSum = <String, double>{};

  for (final name in salesByName.entries) {
    print("${name.key} has ${name.value.length} entries");
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (final sale in name.value) {
      sum += sale['paid'] as double;
    }
    salesByNameSum[name.key] = sum;
  }

  for (final entry in salesByNameSum.entries) {
    print('${entry.key}: ${entry.value}');
  }
```

You would first create a map using `name` as a key and containing a list of sales maps in its value. That way you can easily access the list of each person's transactions.

Then, you could create another smaller map, containing exclusively the `name` as its key, and the `sum` as its value.

Here is a pure-dart DartPad as an example : https://dartpad.dev/?id=2f4e9b102ba931846bc8734c1180b29f

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do it. Following the method used on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60717480), with some additional changes into the logic:

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> sales = [
    {'paid': 2000, 'name': 'person1'},
    {'paid': 2500, 'name': 'person2'},
    {'paid': 5600, 'name': 'person1'},
    {'paid': 974.0, 'name': 'person2'},
  ];
  var result = sales.groupBy((m) => m['name']).map(
        (key, value) => MapEntry(
          key,
          value.fold<double>(0.0, (a, b) => a + b['paid']),
        ),
      );
  print(result);
}

// use this extension
extension Iterables<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Map<K, List<E>> groupBy<K>(K Function(E) keyFunction) => fold(
      <K, List<E>>{},
      (Map<K, List<E>> map, E element) =>
          map..putIfAbsent(keyFunction(element), () => <E>[]).add(element));
}
```

it will produce something like this:

```
{person1: 7600.0, person2: 3474.0}
```

You can try to run it on dartpad.