# How to make sublist to the item in the list which has common

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to sort common age names as sublist to the same age list item here below is the list which contains age and name , here i want to make sublist names to the same age item , need help

```
        class Details {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Details(this.name, this.age);

  List <Details> list = [
    { Jack, 21},
    { Adam, 22},
    { Katherin, 24},
    { john, 22},
    { mike, 21}
  ]
}


Expected :
    
       List <Details> list = [
    { 21: ["jack", "mike",]},
    { 22: ["Adam", "john"]},
    { 24: ["Katherin"]}, ]
```

Comment: Is that help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029370/flutter-dart-how-to-groupby-list-of-maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html) you can find the way to make a sublist of common elements from list item

```
detailsTypeList = groupBy(list, (Details details) => details.age).entries.toList();
```