# Like "GROUP BY" SQL function - structure in Dart for List of Maps

Tags: flutter, dart, group-by, iterable

i want to group data and summarize one value (ctd), this is my data:

```
var data = [
  {"day": 'Monday', "weather": 'warm', 'ctd': 20, 'other':'a'},
  {"day": 'Monday', "weather": 'warm', 'ctd': 15, 'other':'b'},
  {"day": 'Tuesday', "weather": 'cold', 'ctd': 25, 'other':'c'},
  {"day": 'Tuesday', "weather": 'cold', 'ctd': 35, 'other':'d'},
];
```

The result i want is this:

```
  var result = [
    {"day": 'Monday', "weather": 'warm', 'ctd': 35},
    {"day": 'Tuesday', "weather": 'cold', 'ctd': 60},
  ];
```

In SQL i would write something like

```
  SELECT day, weather, sum(ctd) as ctd FROM data GROUP BY day, weather
```

but in Dart i dont get how to accomplish this, i tried with groupBy and fold, but a get a map, and can do only with one key or field.

```
  import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
  ///...
  var result = groupBy(data, (Map obj) => obj['day']).map((key, value) =>
        MapEntry(key, value.fold<int>(0, (p, e) => p + (e['ctd'] as int))));
  print(result); // {Monday: 35, Tuesday: 60}
```

I suspect that the answer is simple, but after having read other answers I can't find it, or I can't imagine it

The most likely question (is not the same) in stack overflow is this [Flutter/Dart how to groupBy list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029370/flutter-dart-how-to-groupby-list-of-maps) where i find how to use the [groupBy](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/groupBy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `package:fast_immutable_collections` to turn your day and weather into a two element IList, which can be used as a map key, and then do your data reduction as you did before.

Answer (score 0):

An approach like this can be generalized and improved, but this is a starting point that works:

```
import 'dart:collection';

List<Map<String, Object>> groupBy(List<Map<String, Object>> list) {
  
  LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, Object>> lmap = LinkedHashMap();
  for (var map in list) {
    if (lmap[(map['day'] as String) + (map['weather'] as String)] == null) {
      lmap[(map['day'] as String) + (map['weather'] as String)] = map;
    } else {
      var t = lmap[(map['day'] as String) + (map['weather'] as String)]!;
      t['ctd'] = (t['ctd'] as int) + (map['ctd'] as int);
    }
  }
  return lmap.entries.map((entry) => entry.value).toList();
}

void main() {
  var data = [
    {"day": 'Monday', "weather": 'warm', 'ctd': 20, 'other': 'a'},
    {"day": 'Monday', "weather": 'warm', 'ctd': 15, 'other': 'b'},
    {"day": 'Tuesday', "weather": 'cold', 'ctd': 25, 'other': 'c'},
    {"day": 'Tuesday', "weather": 'cold', 'ctd': 35, 'other': 'd'},
  ];
  print(groupBy(data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i implemented a version of idea of Randal (Thanks!), and implemented the selection and sum keys as List, as follow

```
keysToSelect = ['day', 'weather'];
keysToSum = ['ctd'];

List<Map<String, dynamic>> dataKeyAsJson = data.map((e) {
    e['asJson'] = {};
    for (var key in keysToSelect) {
      e['asJson'].addAll({key: e[key]});
      e.remove(key);
    }
    e['asJson'] = jsonEncode(e['asJson']);
    return e;
  }).toList();
  // print(dataKeyAsJson);

  Map<dynamic, Map<String, int>> groupAsMap = groupBy(dataKeyAsJson, (Map e) => e['asJson'])
      .map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, {
            for (var keySum in keysToSum)
              keySum: value.fold<int>(0, (p, a) => p + (a[keySum] as int))
          }));
  // print(result2);

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = groupAsMap.entries.map((e) {
    Map<String, dynamic> newMap = jsonDecode(e.key);
    return {...newMap, ...e.value};
  }).toList();
```