# how to group data In flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have just made a demo to clear what I want in my app

Like, I have a class model name Transaction and have some data like below

```
List<Transaction> transactionlist=[
  Transaction(category: 'Food', amount: 100.00),
  Transaction(category: 'Food', amount: 200.00),
  Transaction(category: 'Shopping', amount: 1000.00),
  Transaction(category: 'Shopping', amount: 2000.00),
  Transaction(category: 'Food', amount: 300.00),
  Transaction(category: 'Provision', amount: 500.00),
];
```

Therefor I have created a widget class, Now I want to show all category with its expense total in a list of Map:

```
class ShowCategoryStatus extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<Transaction> transactionlist;
  ShowCategoryStatus({required this.transactionlist});

  List<Map<String,Object>> get amoutbycategory{

//what should I code here to get following list
    /*this getter should return like following way
    [
  {
    'Category':'Food','total':600
  },
  {
    'Category':'Shopping','total':3000.00
  },
  {
    'Category':'Provision','total':500
  }

]


*/


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can so this:

```
    List<Transaction> result = [];
    for (var e in transactionlist) {
      var x = result.where((element) => element.category == e.category);
      if (x.isEmpty) {
        result.add(e);
      } else {
        var newTransaction = Transaction(
            category: e.category, amount: x.first.amount + e.amount);

        result[result.indexOf(x.first)] = newTransaction;
      }
    }
```

now if you print the result you will see what you want:

```
for (var element in result) {
  print("result =${element.category} ${element.amount}"); 
// result =Food 600.0
// result =Shopping 3000.0
// result =Provision 500.0
}
```

**Short Version**:
you can use [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection/install) package, and try this:

```
Map<String, List<Transaction>> grouped =
        groupBy(transactionlist, (value) => value.category);

List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = grouped.entries
    .map((e) => {
          e.key: e.value.fold<double>(0, (total, ele) => total + ele.amount)
        })
    .toList();
```

Comment: I thought there would be simple some facilities....but it looks like I have to done with logic...there is no simple way to solve it..right?

Comment: I tried with this

Comment: Map<String,double>get getcategories
  {
  Map<String,double> categories={};

  transactionlist.forEach((element) {
 if(categories.containsKey(element.category))
     categories[element.category]=double.parse(categories[element.category].toString())+element.amount;
 else
     categories[element.category]=element.amount;
});

  return(categories);

  }

Comment: this returns list<Transactions> but I want List<Map<String,double>>

Comment: was not my question good one? y none ranking it up

Comment: can u do one more favour with updating list with
  {
    'category':'Food',
  'amount':300,
  'totalentries':7
  }

Comment: I didn't get what you want?

Comment: not getting answer..dont know what's wrong with my question...can u pls check my question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209968/how-to-select-multiple-items-while-using-sticky-grouplist-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `groupBy`, `map` and `fold`:

```
  List<Transaction> transactionlist = [
    Transaction(category: 'Food', amount: 100.00),
    Transaction(category: 'Food', amount: 200.00),
    Transaction(category: 'Shopping', amount: 1000.00),
    Transaction(category: 'Shopping', amount: 2000.00),
    Transaction(category: 'Food', amount: 300.00),
    Transaction(category: 'Provision', amount: 500.00),
  ];

  Map<String, List<Transaction>> catGroup =
      groupBy(transactionlist, (val) => val.category);

  Map<String, double> amountMap = catGroup.map((key, value) =>
      MapEntry(key, value.fold(0, (total, ele) => total + ele.amount)));

  print(amountMap);
```

The `groupBy` is used to group all `Transactions` by their category. `map` is used to convert between Maps, and finally `fold` is use to sum up all the amounts of a certain category. You could probably also use `reduce` to sum the amounts here since the iterable should never be empty.

Comment: looks better way...but groupBy showing red line

Comment: Ah yeah. You need to import the package collection `import "package:collection/collection.dart";` from https://pub.dev/packages/collection (official package). You could also write a extension yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60717480/1386873

Answer (score 1):

Best to way to do this, is **put your logic out side of UI**.

You can use `extension` which are very **powerful** & **useful** for this kind of cases.

```
extension TransactionUtils on List<Transaction> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> get categories {
    // create a map for result
    Map<String, double> totalAmounts = {};
    forEach((transaction) {
      totalAmounts.update(
        transaction.category,
        (oldAmount) => oldAmount + transaction.amount,
        ifAbsent: () => transaction.amount,
      );
    });

    //? your data is ready
    // {'Food': 600.0, 'Shopping': 3000.0, 'Provision': 500.0}
    print(totalAmounts);

    //? if you want list of map
    // [
    //   {"category": "Food", "total": 600.0},
    //   {"category": "Shopping", "total": 3000.0},
    //   {"category": "Provision", "total": 500.0}
    // ];
    return totalAmounts.entries
        .map((mapEntry) => {'category': mapEntry.key, 'total': mapEntry.value})
        .toList();
  }
}
```

& in your `UI` you can use following way:

```
void main() {
  final myData = transactionList.categories;
}
```

You can find detailed explanation about `extension` on [Vandad's blog](https://vandad.sh/dart-extensions/).

Answer (score 0):

hope you are fine,

Simple and slightly hard coded answer: you need to loop over list and check for category to sum amount and then return result.

```
void main() {
 List<Transaction> transactions=[
 Transaction(category: 'Food', amount: 100.0),
 Transaction(category: 'Food', amount: 200.0),
 Transaction(category: 'Shopping', amount: 1000.0),
 Transaction(category: 'Shopping', amount: 2000.0),
 Transaction(category: 'Food', amount: 300.0),
 Transaction(category: 'Provision', amount: 500.0),
 ];

 Transaction.amountByCategory(transactions);
 print(Transaction.amountByCategory(transactions)
 );
}

class Transaction{
 String? category;
 double? amount;
 Transaction({this.category, this.amount});

 static List<Map<String, dynamic>> amountByCategory(List<Transaction> 
 transactions) {
   var foodAmount = 0.0;
   var shoppingAmount = 0.0;
   var provisionAmount = 0.0;

   transactions.map((transaction) {
    switch(transaction.category){
      case "Food":
      foodAmount += transaction.amount!.toDouble();
      break;
     
      case "Shopping":
      shoppingAmount += transaction.amount!.toDouble();
      break;
     
      case "Provision":
      provisionAmount += transaction.amount!.toDouble();
      break;
   }}).toList();

return [
  {
    "Category": "Food",
    "total": foodAmount,
  },
   {
    "Category": "Shopping",
    "total": shoppingAmount,
  },
   {
    "Category": "Provision",
    "total": provisionAmount,
   },
  ];
 },
}
```

> code link -> https://dartpad.dev/?

- hope I could help, have a nice day :)