# List of map - merge same value with single element

Tags: javascript, flutter, list, dart

I have list like below

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Aaa",
    "title": "Aaa like your photo"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Bbb",
    "title": "Bbb like your video"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Ccc",
    "title": "Ccc like your photo"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Ddd",
    "title": "Ddd like your photo"
  }
]
```

I want to merge `map` with same `id` and result would be

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Aaa, Ccc and Ddd",
    "title": "Aaa, Ccc and Ddd like your photo"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Bbb",
    "title": "Bbb like your video"
  }
]
```

I know nester `forEach` loop but looking for any short way.

Comment: use [groupListsBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/groupListsBy.html)

Comment: SO what do you want the answer in? Multiple things posted there....

Comment: As already noted, choose a language

Comment: also the [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) and [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object) for general group-by answers.

Comment: or for dart [Flutter/Dart how to groupBy list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029370/flutter-dart-how-to-groupby-list-of-maps)

Comment: Regardless of context, I highly doubt it would ever be beneficial for the **identifier** (`id`) to not be unique. If you want something to group them together, just add another parameter to the object related to grouping and keep the identifier unique. Furthermore, wouldn't you want to merge the `name` and `title` on the frontend interface rather than merging the existing data? I would recommend merging them in a list or array rather than actually merging the objects themselves. Obviously, this depends on use-cases, just struggle to imagine where something like this would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend implementing something like the following where you create a new object that has `id` keys and values of lists of the object.name values. Using the following example list input you gave, if you did something like

```
function mergeObjectsWithSameId(inputArray) {
    return inputArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (!acc[curr.id]) {
        acc[curr.id] = [];
      }
      acc[curr.id].push(curr.name);
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }
```

would give you the following output:

```
{
  "1": ["Aaa", "Ccc" "Ddd"],
  "2": ["Bbb"]
  ]
}
```

You could likely drop the `title` part of your list as well and then use each `name` from a given key to display which `name`'s have liked a photo, ex:

```
const names = mergeObjectsWithSameId(input);
// If we want to display all names that "liked" a photo with id of "1"
const stringToDisplay = `${names.join(', ')} liked your photo`; // "Aaa, Ccc, Ddd liked your photo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly review the code provided below. I believe it may be beneficial.

```
void main() {
  String jsonString = '''
    [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Aaa",
    "title": "Aaa like your photo"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Bbb",
    "title": "Bbb like your video"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Ccc",
    "title": "Ccc like your photo"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Ddd",
    "title": "Ddd like your photo"
  }
]
  ''';

  var data = List<Map<String, String>>.from(jsonDecode(jsonString));

  var result = <String, Map<String, String>>{};

  data.forEach((element) {
    var id = element['id'];
    result[id] = {
      'id': id!,
      'name': '${result[id]?['name'] ?? ''}, ${element['name']!}',
      'title': '${result[id]?['title'] ?? ''}, ${element['title']!}'
    };
  });

  print(result.values.toList());
}
```